# Why doesn't jQuery ".css" work with variables?

Tags: jquery

`.css()` works in this case:

```
if ($(toggle.targetEl).css('opacity') === '0') {
    // some code
} else {
    // more code
}
```

However it doesn't work if you do this:

```
const $targetEl = $(toggle.targetEl)
if ($targetEl.css('opacity') === '0') {
    // $targetEl.css('opacity') => undefined
```

Is this jQuery's default behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

The last example doesn't output any errors. And `console.log($targetEl)` shows:

```
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".map"]
```

**EDIT 2:**

**directive.js:**

```
export const toggle = {
  update: function (toggle) {
    const $el = $(this.el)
    const $targetEl = $(toggle.targetEl)
    console.log($targetEl)
    $el.click(() => {
      if ($targetEl.css('opacity') === '0') {
        $(toggle.targetEl).css('visibility', 'visible')
        $(toggle.targetEl).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200)
      } else {
        // hide element when opacity animation is done
        $(toggle.targetEl).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200, () => {
          $(toggle.targetEl).css('visibility', 'hidden')
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**component.vue:**

```
<button class="toggle-map" v-toggle="toggle">
  <i class="fa fa-map"></i>
</button>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      toggle: {
        targetEl: '.map'
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It all depends on what type of variable is stored in `$targetEl`. If it's a jQuery object, it should work fine. If it's not, then you will most likely get a syntax error in the console.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated the code.

Comment: The two code snippets are logically identical. I'm unable to replicate the error; the code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/gtm2cgq4/. We need more information to diagnose the issue, any errors in the console and also a more complete code sample where you set `toggle` and its properties.

Comment: Are the `$targetEl =...` and `if ($targetEl...)` statements in your code next to each other like in the example, or further apart? In particular, is the `if` inside a function, and `$targetEl =...` outside it?

Comment: I posted the full code.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I posted the full code. There are no errors in the console other than the `undefined` that `console.log($targetEl.css('opacity'))` outputs.

Comment: I don't know almost anything about vue.js, so can't tell you for sure; but the most likely problem is that `$(toggle.targetEl)` does not exist at the time of `update`, but does exist at the time of the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issues in this way:

```
const $el = $(this.el)
  $el.click(() => {
    const $targetEl = $(toggle.targetEl)
    if ($targetEl.css('opacity') === '0') {
    // some code
```

It's a scope problem with `const` ... though I'm not very sure.